# Facebook Token/Session Strategy

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, facebook

I'm working with the latest version of the Facebook SDK, and things have changed a bit from the last version I had used.

In the past I would use the FBSession class to observe whether or not a user opens the app with a valid token that hasn't expired.

The handy old method:

```
openActiveSessionWithAllowLoginUI
```

Would detect if the session was still valid and, if not, prompt the user to login again.

The FBSession class has been deprecated and I cannot find any equivalent method in the new sdk.

There are methods to do what I want manually, but I wanted to reach out and see if there is a new strategy for handling this situation:

```
– see if there is a token:
    • if yes, refresh it longer
    • if no, login again
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean v4.x of the Facebook SDK with "the new version" `FBSDKLoginManager`/`FBSDKAccessToken` is what you are looking for to check for an existing session and logging in again.

From the [SDK Upgrade Guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/upgrading-4.x):

> LoginManager logIn: methods always open a UI. There is no direct
>   equivalent to v3.x's FBSession's allowLoginUI: flag. Instead, you
>   should check [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] at viewDidLoad or
>   similar. If a current token is available, do the post-login work. You
>   can also use currentAccessToken to retrieve cached tokens.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I am doing. I didn't see that official statement from Facebook.